# DDA Program using C

Tags: c, access-violation

I am running a DDA program but it shows **"Unhandled exception thrown: write access violation. k was 0x1FFF112."**

```
/*------------------------------------------------*/
      /* vi-vj contact                       vi concave */
      /* 2 v-e contact v_j-e_i+1 e_i       v_j-e_ie_i-1 */
                      if ((x1-x3)*(x1-x3)+(yi-y3)*(yi-y3)> d0*d0) goto a404;
                      if (u[i][2] < 180+.0001) goto a402;
                      m6+=1;
                      k[m6]  = (-1)*j;
                      k1[m6] =      i;
      /*------------------------------------------------*/
                      m6+=1;
                      k[m6]  = (-1)*j;
                      k1[m6] =    i-1;
                      if (i==k0[ii][1])  k1[m6] = k0[ii][2];
                      goto a406;
      /*------------------------------------------------*/
      /* vi-vj contact                       vj concave */
      /* 2 v-e contact v_i-e_j+1 e_j       v_i-e_je_i-j */
 a402:;
                      if (u[j][2] < 180+.0001) goto a403;
                      m6+=1;
                      k[m6]  = (-1)*i;
                      k1[m6] =      j;
      /*------------------------------------------------*/
```

Comment: That sounds like `m6` is not a valid index for either the `k` or `k1` arrays. Also, C++ and C are different languages. Please only one tag.

Comment: For me, there is some missing context. What do you mean with DDA? I found more than one possible answer. Do you have a source code? What compiler do you use? From which system does this message come from? (Maybe be a bit more specific with your tags, i know the topics of your tags very well but i have no idea what you trying to do)

Comment: Actually the code is consist of around 6000 lines, the space is not  enough for input all of the code. This is is written in C. DDA means discontinous deformation analysis, I am going to use this code to check the behaviour of a structure due to earthquake load. Is there any way that I can contact you? Thank you!